# Site is Working fine without any error

Tags: magento

I have a site in magento (Latest version). The site is working fine without any error but sometime site didn't load and a white screen appears. This issue then automatically resolved after some time.
Can anyone help me. Here is the site url.
http://egolfoutlet.ae

Comment: You should check your error logs. What hosting you are using?

Comment: The site egolfoutlet.ae is working 100% fine now with greater level of improvement in performance.

Answer (score 1):

Blank white pages are usually a sign that a fatal PHP error has occurred, and error reporting in PHP is turned off.  Check your apache error logs (how you'll do this and the log file location varies depending on your web host).

Magento also has it's own error reporting system where it shows a friendly page to the end user and drops the actual PHP error message and stack trace into a file in `var/report`.

The report files will have a numeric file name and can be opened with any text editor.

If you are not seeing any error reports, it would be worth making sure your web server can write to the `var/report` folder.

Magento documentation generally recommends 777 permissions for the `var` folder and everything within it.

Comment: The site egolfoutlet.ae is working 100% fine now with greater level of improvement in performance.